# Phonegap device.platform usage in HTML5 body

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I am trying to play sound file in native apps created using Phonegap.  I don't wan't to play it when a certain page is loaded.  Instead I would like to play it after the page is loaded and user taps on Play.   The challenge I am facing is that most of the platforms have different paths for a sound file.  For example:

Android:

```
playAudio('/android_asset/www/voice.m4a')
```

and for iOS:

```
playAudio('voice.m4a')
```

I have been able to detect the platform by using the code below but I am having trouble calling the right HTML so that only one of the two above show based on the platform.

[PhoneGap Documentation: device.platform](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.platform)

Comment: To clarify below is the code I am using to determine the device platform.   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = device.platform;  // If i do a string comparison by using if (element == "Android) { var myfolder = "/android_asset/www/"; } else { var myfolder ="/otherfolder";}  The value of myfolder doesn't get passed into the body.  For example, <p id="myfolder"></p> won't display the folder value